# Adding nested resource in Rails API that doesn't require top resource id in path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes, rails-api

I'm brand new to Rails and Ruby development, so I apologize if this was answered somewhere, I couldn't find anything addressing my exact question.

Let's say I want to add a RESTful endpoint to a resource, let's say "form". The default CRUD actions I'm using to actually edit and create forms. I want to add an endpoint to allow a POST to submit a form. Let's not get bogged down in the plan and design of this, I use this just as an example to make my question clear. If I make "submission" a nested resource (which doesn't really make sense to me anyway - submission is an action, not a resource in this case), the route generated for me expects an :id for the associated form. I get that. So something like this is what is generated:

/forms/:id/submission

However let's say I want to still have /forms in the url (so doesn't seem like I want a shallow path scope - i.e. I'm not looking to do /submission) to look like this:

/forms/submission

How can I do this? Is my problem that I'm trying to fit a square peg into a round hole with making it a resource? Do I need to resort to something explicit and non-RESTful like this outside of my resource route:

post "forms/submission" => 'forms#submission'

If I'm missing something more Rails/Ruby specific please let me know, because I'm still learning. However I get the feeling it's more of a REST issue and me going about it incorrectly.

Basically, I already have a POST action to create a form, so at the end of the day I'm just trying to add another POST action to the resource "forms" but without requiring a form id in the path, but still wanting form in the path. In this case I don't care which form the user has submitted, we treat them all the same, so the id isn't relevant. The only time I care about the form id is when a form is being requested or edited.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a namespace.

At your routes file:

```
namespace :forms do
  resources :something
end
```

Comment: Will this still work if I want the default CRUD routes for a "forms" resource in addition?